# What is the reason behind the direction of field lines of positive and negative charge

Tags: electric-fields

I had a doubt in my mind that why the direction of field lines of a positive charge is toward outwards and of a negative charge toward inward direction

Comment: [The direction of the electric field is always directed in the direction that a positive test charge would be pushed or pulled if placed in the space surrounding the source charge.](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/estatics/Lesson-4/Electric-Field-Lines) This question was already [asked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/288172/why-is-electric-field-lines-away-from-and-toward) and answered.

Comment: There is no significant "reason" as such. Someone back in the past just decided to represent field lines according to the behavior of a **positive** test charge. Same choice for current directions, magnetic fields etc. The choice could just as well have been opposite.

Answer (score 2):

It's a convention so that we can easily use the Coulomb interaction to determine the trajectory of charged particles in an electric field.